# Angularjs 1.5.7 ng-change from component does not work

Tags: angularjs, components

I use angularjs 1.5.7 and try use component way with it but I meet problem with ng-change. Ng-change does not work with $ctrl property bind via '='. Can anyone explain why it does not work?

Look at outerModel. This property using in input as ngModel value.

Component code:

```
"use strict";

CrmApp.component('inputNumber', {
    templateUrl: function ($attrs) {
        return $attrs.templateUrl || '/templates/components/inputNumber.html';
    },
    bindings: {
        'step': '<',
        'min': '<',
        'max': '<',
        'required': '<',
        'disableText': '<',
        'resetOnOverflow': '<',
        'outerModel': '=',
        'changeCallback': '&',
        'doubledZero': '<',
    },
    controller: function($rootScope, $scope, $element) {
        let ctrl = this;
        let input = $element.find('input');
        ctrl.changeCallback = ctrl.changeCallback();

        ctrl.descritizeUnceratainVisitMinutes = function (value) {
            if (+value > 0 && +value <= 15) {
                ctrl.outerModel = 15;
            } else if (+value > 15 && +value <= 30) {
                ctrl.outerModel = 30;
            } else if (+value > 30 && +value <= 45) {
                ctrl.outerModel = 45;
            } else {
                ctrl.outerModel = 0;
            }

            return ctrl.outerModel;
        };

        ctrl.test = function () {
            alert(123);
            console.log(123);
        }
    }
});
```

Template of component:

```
<input
    ng-model="$ctrl.outerModel"
    ng-required="$ctrl.required"
    ng-change="$ctrl.test();"
    name="$ctrl.name"
>
```

How I use component:

```
                <input-number
                    class="e-time-part__uncertain-visit"
                    min="0"
                    required="true"
                    disable-text="true"
                    reset-on-overflow="true"
                    outer-model="visit.hours"
                    change-callback="changeVisitCallback"
                    name="hours"
                >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank all, I found issue with my code. 
I used spinner https://jqueryui.com/spinner/ that not correctly update UI. This issue solved by updating UI via $setViewValue:

```
let ngModel = angular.element(input).controller('ngModel');
ngModel.$setViewValue(+ui.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Code wise I do not think there is any issue. Might be your template could have some issues.
Even I tried to execute it with angular1.5.7 version and its working fine.

### Working code is attached below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<script>


      angular.module('mainModule', [])
         .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$window', function($scope, $rootScope, $window) {
        $scope.visit = {hours: 1200};

         }])

.component('inputNumber', {
    template: '<input ng-model="$ctrl.outerModel" ng-required="$ctrl.required" ng-change="$ctrl.test();" name="$ctrl.name">',
    bindings: {
        'step': '<',
        'min': '<',
        'max': '<',
        'required': '<',
        'disableText': '<',
        'resetOnOverflow': '<',
        'outerModel': '=',
        'changeCallback': '&',
        'doubledZero': '<',
    },
    controller: function($rootScope, $scope, $element) {
        let ctrl = this;
        let input = $element.find('input');
        ctrl.changeCallback = ctrl.changeCallback();

        ctrl.descritizeUnceratainVisitMinutes = function (value) {
            if (+value > 0 && +value <= 15) {
                ctrl.outerModel = 15;
            } else if (+value > 15 && +value <= 30) {
                ctrl.outerModel = 30;
            } else if (+value > 30 && +value <= 45) {
                ctrl.outerModel = 45;
            } else {
                ctrl.outerModel = 0;
            }

            return ctrl.outerModel;
        };

        ctrl.test = function () {
            alert(123);
            console.log(123);
        }
    }
});
    </script>
<body ng-app="mainModule">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<input-number
                    class="e-time-part__uncertain-visit"
                    min="0"
                    required="true"
                    disable-text="true"
                    reset-on-overflow="true"
                    outer-model="visit.hours"
                    change-callback="changeVisitCallback"
                    name="hours"
                >
</div>

</body>
</html>
```